# Query regarding using MSDN license

Tags: msdn

If I buy one of the available MSDN subscriptions from Professional, Premium, Ultimate and Test Professional then how many developers can download & use the products?

Comment: How is this off topic? It's about a product which is used almost entirely by developers. He could also ask someone else who knows the answer, maybe on StackOverflow.

Comment: You need to talk to your reseller, not SO. Generally, though, MSDN is licensed per developer, i.e. one licence: one developer.

Comment: @Charles: is it ever not per-developer? There may be different levels of volume license or so, but one license == one developer. Always, as far as I know.

Comment: @John Saunders: It's not a question about a product that's used by developers, though, it's a question about licensing the software. The licensing activity is not specific to programming.

Comment: @Charles: licensing this _particular_ product is indeed specific to programming. This isn't a general question about licensing products in general, it's a specific question about licensing MSDN.

Comment: @John Saunders: Can we agree to differ? For me it's definitely one level too indirect to make it programming related.

Answer (score 4):

One. The subscriptions are per-developer.

Comment: So, does that mean if I purchase 'Visual Studio 2010 Test Professional', I have to pay USD 3769 per developer?

Comment: @Kabeer: if that's the price, then yes, it's per-developer.

Comment: Thanks. But I am shattered :(

Comment: Depending on the region and country, they may have offers that can help small businesses and startups. See http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/. Be sure to take a look at the links at the bottom of the page in case this particular program doesn't suit you.

Comment: In the licensing it states one per developer.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx